# Missing margin/padding in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have a header menu, with square images and a margin around each image.

**Problem:** If there are many elements, the right-margin of the last image vanishes and so does the right-padding of the ul.

**Desired outcome:** I'd like there to be 10px of space to the right of the last image.

Note: I **cannot** use any `:first-child` or `:first-child` to give the li different margins. This is because of some sorting animation that can't deal with that.

(The second header is just there to illustrate that I need ul to be a flexbox, because with only two images they need to have the remaining space spread around them.)

```css
header {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<header>    
    <ul>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>    
    </ul>
  </header>
  
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Comment: Can you not just add some `left-padding` to the `<ul>` element to simulate the extra margin?  it sounds like you want to only target the last element, but you say you can't use the `:last-child` to target it.

Comment: Why don't you use `inline-flex` for the top `<ul>`?

Comment: @DmitryS.That works! If I also add `min-width: calc(100% + 10px)` to it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because your tell the div's to be a fixed with flex has a hard time working all this out. Your items are 320px alltogether while your container is only 300px wide. So it will overflow (as you've defined). In this case the ul actually has margin on the side, but you overwrite that behavior by making your container smaller then the minimum width of it's contents.

You can also add some padding to your header, and put the overflow scroll on your ul.

```
header {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```
<header>    
    <ul>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>    
    </ul>
  </header>

  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><div></div></li>
      <li><div></div></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```